# How do I use $.when to call an $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Okay, I need some help.

```
var DeletarArquivo = fnDeletarArquivo(hashArquivo);
$.when(DeletarArquivo).then(function (theData) {
    //do something
    });
```

The function `fnDeletarArquivo` its used to delete files. It is here:

```
function fnDeletarArquivo(hashArquivo){
    var parametros = {
        strHashArquivo: hashArquivo
    };
    var parametros = jQuery.param(parametros);
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "uploader/apagarArquivo.asp",
        data: parametros
    });
}
```

The file `apagarArquivo.asp` works when I access it by querystrings: `http://uploader/apagarArquivo.asp?strHashArquivo=216daf162a3c3fd659d91d4e617af067`

But, by using ajax it does not.
What i am missing up? I already tried calling:

```
fnDeletarArquivo(hashArquivo);
//do something
```

but it still not working.

Can you please help me?

Comment: your ajax is POSTING the data rather than creating a query string. shouldn't you be using GET instead?

Comment: Check your developer console network tab to make sure the ajax request is using the same URL and that response is successful.  As Kevin mentions you are posting, and I am guessing the asp page only looks in query string value and not posted values.  You will have to look at the asp code to verify.

Comment: **How** is it not working? What is the problem?

Comment: @Kevin B: Thanks it works!! Please answer so I can close!

Comment: @UderMoreira Chilpol has it

Comment: Just to note: it's considered bad practice to use GET if the action alters content on the server. It's safer to switch back to POST and alter your ASP file to read from `request.form` instead of `request.querystring`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you tried:

`http://uploader/apagarArquivo.asp?strHashArquivo=216daf162a3c3fd659d91d4e617af067`

in a web browser, the method used is defaulted to `GET`.

I could see that your ajax request is `POST` . You can try to change the type from `POST` to `GET` and see if it helped.